# How to create a static block which displays all categories

Tags: category, static-block

I want to create a static block which displays all of my categories and displays them in a list. I don't need an image and I don't need the sub categories.

Then I want to add this block to my home page.

Answer (score 6):

Create one `.phtml` file inside `app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog` lets name it as `homecategories.phtml` and paste this code into it

```
  <!-- Categories display start -->
        <div class="home_categories">
              <ul>
                   <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
                 <?php foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
                 <li>
                     <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                 </li>
                 <?php endforeach ?>
              </ul>

        </div>
         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>

        <!-- Categories display end -->
```

now create a static block lets name it as `homecategories` id as `home_categories` and now place this code into content of that block `{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/homecategories.phtml"}}` now call this static block in  your `cms.xml` in this way

```
<block type="cms/block" name="homecategories">
   <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home_categories</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Comment: I noticed that you can also add this: {{block type="core/template" template="catalog/homecategories.phtml"}} to any static block to display main categories anywhere. However this does not show sub categories and I need that too.

Answer (score 1):

Create a static block from admin
Then

create a local.xml file under `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/layout` and past the below code

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <layout version="0.1.0">
        <catalog_category_layered>

                <reference name="category.products">
                    <block type="cms/block" name="cat_static_block" >
                        <!--
                            The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                            You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
                        -->
                        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>yourblock_id</block_id></action>
                    </block>
                </reference>
        </catalog_category_layered>
           <catalog_category_default>

                <reference name="category.products">
                    <block type="cms/block" name="cat_static_block" >
                        <!--
                            The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                            You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
                        -->
                        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>yourblock_id</block_id></action>
                    </block>
                </reference>
        </catalog_category_default>
    </layout>
```

and goto `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`
add code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cat_static_block');?>`

Comment: sorry where do i create this local.xml ? and what do i put in my static block content in admin ??

Comment: yes,you need cms static  block from admih...

Comment: i have created a Static block with the ID all_cat_home but i need to put something in the content filed on the admin page. What do i write in there?