# List all categories in footer

Tags: magento-1.9, category, custom, footer

I want to list all the categories in footer. Need the solution for both with and without sub-categories. something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list of all the categories along with the url using the below code

**This will display all top level categories:**

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**To display all top level and subcategories use below code:**

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: where do i have to put this code?

Comment: You can put this code in your footer file ie:  `footer.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml` or you can create a new template file with new position and put it in there.

Comment: put that code right at the end of footer.phtml
but not working

Comment: what is the problem?? its working perfectly fine in my system

Comment: no error, nothing changed, the frontend is same like before. you can have a look at zumastic.com

Comment: have you cleared the cache? try clearing the cache and doing reindexing...

Comment: They are visible now. But it is showing as list view. can it be change to grid view ?

Comment: you can change in which ever view you want.. you need to write css for it.. Also if you found the answer helpful please mark it as accepted so it can help the future readers

Comment: First I did this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30832/how-to-create-a-static-block-which-displays-all-categories Then I applied the code in this answer and I got the full list of categories and subcategories to static block in footer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
$root_category_id =  Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root_category_id);

function getCategories($category, $withSubcategories = false)
{
    $children = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    foreach ($children as $cat)
    {
        echo $cat->getName()."<br>";
        if($withSubcategories){
            getCategories($cat, true);
        }
    }
}
```

end after that if you need only main categories without sub-categories, only call:

```
getCategories($root_category);
```

and if you need with sub-categories:

```
getCategories($root_category, true);
```

of course you can format it as you want. This is only example how to fetch and echo catgories

Comment: where do i have to put this code?

Comment: you can put it into: `app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/template/page/html/footer.phtml`